# smtp header / body separator

Tags: bash, smtp

I need to separate the header and body of a smtp message in bash. I know that a newline is used to indicate the end of the header, but is it always `\n`, `\r` or  `\r\n`, or do different operating systems use different ones?

How can I do this?

Comment: It's always `\r\n` in the message itself. However, most likely whatever program you're using will convert the line ending to the correct one for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was defined originally in [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) and it is `CR LF`. Look at section 3.1.

> 3.1. GENERAL DESCRIPTION
> A message consists of header fields and, optionally, a body. The body is simply a sequence of lines containing ASCII characters. It is separated from the headers by a null line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF).

---

The most recent version is [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1) and the relevant section is now 2.1.
It is more comprehensive, but has still the same content, i.e. the separator is CRLF.